# Max value decrease when I'm using “Hall of fame” function in Python DEAP package

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, deap

DEAP is an awesome Python package to supporting evolution algorithm.

Now, I'm learn it from the simple example [OneMax Problem](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_onemax_short.html)

With *HallofFame* **on**, "it will keep track of the best individual to appear in the evolution (it keeps it even in the case it extinguishes) "

But when I use it, the max fitness of population through the evolution process decrease a little bit sometimes.

I think when the best parents are left, the fitness.Max should never decrease but keep the same or increase.

Here is the code which I directly copied in DEAP website.

```
import array
import random

import numpy

from deap import algorithms
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", array.array, typecode='b', fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

# Attribute generator
toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)

# Structure initializers
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_bool, 100)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

def evalOneMax(individual):
    return sum(individual),

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalOneMax)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoint)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)

def main():
    random.seed(64)

    pop = toolbox.population(n=300)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max)

    pop, log = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.2, ngen=40, 
                                   stats=stats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    return pop, log, hof

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I can try to elaborate if needed. Cheers.

The max fitness decrease in the generation 3:

[image]

Comment: `hof` is just a container to keep track of best possible individuals so far. In the end, if you print `hof[0]` you will see the best one generated throughout the algorithm. It doesn't mean the best one is included in each generation. With mutation and mating those can change. Actually that's why you store the best one(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, the best individual of generation _n_ may be deleted due to the mutation or mate, but its score will be saved in the `hof`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Not its score though, the solution itself will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

The fitness max value that appears in the statistics is the maximum fitness *in the current population*, not of all individuals that ever were evaluated. In the `eaSimple` algorithm, there is no mechanism for keeping the best solution, so it is not unusual for the fitness max to decrease sometimes.

Using the `HallOfFame` does not guarantee that the best individual will stay in the population. It just makes a copy of the best individual that you can use once the algorithm is done running.